# Javax and org imports are not working tried everything. Nothing works why?

Tags: maven, netbeans-7

I am creating a betfair api in maven netbeans however it claims the javax.we.rs and org.glassfish.jersey packages do not exist. I have read all material but nothing works.

Comment: You need to add the necessary dependencies to your project. Also, you probably want to import `javax.ws.rs`, not `javax.we.rs`.

Comment: I right click on dependencies and try to add javax.ws.rs and it says to general and doesn't find the package.

Comment: A dependency is a library, you need to find the right library and add it to your project.

Comment: Thanks I now understand you just need to add dependencies to the pom file and it does the rest for you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This was my first Maven project